# how to link from an html to another component in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have created 2 components in angular called(`course` and `courseDetails`) in same module called(`Student`).Now i want to get access to "courseDetails'html file" from "course' html file" through a link click.. i.e when user is in `course` section and clicks on a link provide,the link should redirect it to "courseDetails'html". assume all routing is done of both components in module.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32jP6.png)

[image]

Comment: hey, why you are using href here ? as you are using angular use routerLink. for more details check here -> https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it as text

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `routerLink` instead of `href` try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

> **Angular Guide for Routing** - https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

use routerLink like some suggested above and place your tag like this example here `<a mat-button routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Login</a>` this is just a case of using mat-button. In your routerLink you must have a route to the destination you want it to go..........e.g  login as in this case.